# Is configuring entitlements for Mac App Store application a must?

Tags: macos, store, entitlements

I am going to submit my application for Mac App Store, and I am confused about enabling entitlements.
In [Apple developer guide for configuring your app for mac App store](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/ConfiguringApplications/ConfiguringApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH3-SW1/), it does not say if it is required, or its just better to do it.

I am not using iCloud or push notifications (and are not enabled in my App ID).

I am not going to enable Sandboxing before 1st of March.
I sign my executable with the appropriate Apple Application Certificate and my installer with Installer certificate.

I am following the File-System Usage Requirements for the Mac App Store guide lines.

Last time my binary was accepted, but application was rejected in review due to some other violation.
My question is, will my app get rejected if I do not check the **Enable Entitlements** checkbox in Xcode. If I enable it, the second option is if I want to enable Sandbox which I do not, so it seems irrelevant.
I found [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/92151-do-you-have-enable-entitlement-get-accepted-app-store.html) answer which says its not required but its for iOS.
Can someone confirm?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not needed. My App was approved without Enabling entitlements. But, it will be needed once I start using Push notifications, Sandboxing, or iClouds.